# Select all records from one table that only have one corresponding record in another table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, one contains records that need to be associated with the other in order to exist so the I filled them with a default value if there were none. I just can't seem to figure out how to select out records from the first table that only have the default record in the second.

For example id 1, 4, and 5 in table A has 3 records aside from the default associated with it while id's 2 and 3 have only the default record.

How would I select out just records that only contain the default record?

Comment: Can you post the table structure for both tables, maybe sprinkle in some sample data.  Also, what have you tired so far?  People on SO are far more inclined to help if we can see the table structures and what you've attempted so far.

Comment: You can do it with a correlated subquery in the WHERE clause.

Comment: How do you distinguish the default record from "real" ones?

Comment: Sorry, new to posting on SO so I don't actually know how to insert the table structures, when I tried it posted it out as a sentence. I may just delete the questio

Comment: Select any code or formatted text, and then click the "{}" icon in the formatting bar at the top.